# How do I pass a parameter from javascript into webview (java) in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-webview, android-websettings, android-json-rpc

I have the following javascript:

```
public String jscode() {
String myString = "javascript:function myscript() {" +
"     var _$b = window._$b= { version: \"1.0\"};" +
"     _$b.navigate = function(url, title) {" +
                "     rpc.exec(" +// JSON-RPC 2.0
                "              {method: \"navigate\", " +
                "      params: {" +
                "              \"url\": url," +
                "              \"title\": title" +
                "              }});" +
                "       local_url = url;" +

                "      };" +
                "};"


    return myString;

}
```

Now I am using it in webview onpagefinished such that:

```
String newString = jscode();
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                            view.evaluateJavascript(newString, null);
                            view.evaluateJavascript("myscript();", null);


                        }
```

How do I pass the value of "navigate" parameter local_url into the evaluatejavascript function? I looked online for a couple of tutorials but none of them seemed to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pass arguments to the url you are opening in the webview. 
If that is the case, try using `Uri.Builder` class to append the parameters to the url you pass to the webview.

`Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
                .appendQueryParameter("param1", value1)
                .appendQueryParameter("param2", value2);
        final String params = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();
web_view.loadUrl("your url" + params);`

Hope it helps!